# Single Photon Pulses in Qiskit Pulse?

Tags: qiskit, openpulse

Is it possible to obtain/control something akin to a $\pi$ pulse consisting only of a single photon in Qiskit Pulse? For instance, if I wanted to perform an implementation of something like Aharonov, Cohen, Elitzur's "[Quantum Liar Paradox](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-017-0127-y)" which involves generating a Bell state with two qubits by the possibility of exchange of a single photon between them, could this be done in Qiskit?

I have read the documentation extensively and have latched onto things like the [implementation of Jaynes-Cummings dynamics with Qiskit pulse](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/Jaynes-Cummings-model.html) which involves the probabilistic spontaneous decay of the atom which then releases a single photon into the cavity. Could something like this be modified to use a two-level qubit/transmon prepared in its first excited state as a probabilistic single-photon source to excite a target qubit?

Of course, this is possible physically, and so by using one of the actual quantum device backends that Qiskit affords, it seems that something like this or analogous to it should be possible. However, this would seem to involve having an understanding of the underlying physics of the quantum backends and the systems on which they are implemented which I can't find great documentation for.

I know that things like QuTIP or PhotoniQLAB are somewhat better-suited for single-photon source manipulation and simulation, but assume I have my reasons for wanting to stick with Qiskit.